# Repository.Save() inside scheduling is not working

Tags: jpa, spring-transactions

I have a repository.save() method called inside a scheduler. But it is not saving anything to the database. 
Following is my scheduler

```
@Component
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class WomConditionActionJob {


@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Autowired
private ECCRepository eCCRepository;

@Autowired
private WOCRepository wOCRepository;

@Autowired
private PSRepository pSRepository;


@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${wCATrigger.polling.frequency}", initialDelayString = "${wCATrigger.initial.delay}")
public void execute() {

    try {
            final PauseStatus pause = pSRepository.findByPSName(PSName.PAUSE);
            pauseCondition(pause,threshold);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception Occured {}", e);
    }

}

private void pauseCondition(final PauseStatus pause, final Integer threshold) {
        WOTCondition wotCId = workOrderConditionRepository.findById(1).get();
        wotCId.setPauseStatus(pause);
        wotCId.setIsUserAction(Boolean.FALSE);
        workOrderConditionRepository.save(wotConditionbyId);
        conditionCount.setErrorCount(0);
        errorConditionCountRepository.save(conditionCount);
    }
}
```

**I trying using saveAndFlush() but that time I got Following error**

> [pool-2-thread-1]|ERROR|[o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError(96)]|Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
>   org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: **Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only**
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:873)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:710)

Comment: Where does the conditionCount variable come from?

Comment: It is just a model. When I simplify the code it has removed. Just Ignore that saving.

Comment: Ok, for my experience it has to be a previous error message that tell you the root cause of the error, on the other hand my first approach to solve this would be to create a separate bean to do the transactional operations and invoke it from the scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this solved my issue

```html
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Example

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * *")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Override
public void scheduleJob() {
            
  Message message = new Message();
  message.setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
  message.setAccountId("accountId");
  message.setSent(2L);
  message.setFailed(2L);
  message.setDelivered(2L);
        
  // saves or update message_report table
  messageRepository.save(message);
             
}
```

Comment: OMFG THANK YOU! Why does this work though?